# Why does the tex filename matter in this case?

Tags: pdftex

Brand new here (sorry if I should have learned this already). I want to create a series of pdf files containing nothing but jpeg images, and have created the following tex file:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\includegraphics[scale=2]{001.jpeg}
\end{document}
```

This works fine if I name the file say 001.tex, but if I rename the file to 001.jpeg.tex, then `/usr/local/texlive/2021/bin/x86_64-linux/pdflatex 001.jpeg.tex` fails with the following error message:

```
!pdfTeX error: /usr/local/texlive/2021/bin/x86_64-linux/pdflatex (file ./001.jp
eg.tex): unknown type of image
 ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
```

The processor (in the second case) just seems to ignore the file explicitly specified in the tex file (and adds a .tex extension to it). While I can work around the problem for this specific task, it appears that I don't understand something fairly basic, which could come back to bite me in the future.

Can someone explain why this happens? Thank you in advance.

Comment: possibly unrelated note it is better to set the system path and use `pdflatex file` rather than use form `/usr/local/texlive/2021/bin/x86_64-linux/pdflatex file`  . Then because tex adds the .tex extension automatically it is hard to always destinguish two files that just differ by having a .tex extension so if your files are `001.jpeg` and `001.jpeg.tex`  then tex getting confused isn't that surprising